# Basic UIImageView Question

Tags: objective-c

Hey guys when you set the coordinates of a UIImageView it sets the UIImageView respective to the top right corner. Is there any way to make the coordinates apply to the bottom left?

Answer (score 1):

if you have the reference of the view then you can set its anchor point uisng 
`view.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,1);` //your lower left corner..

0,0 means upper left corner
 default is 0.5,0.5 which is center 
max is 1,1 which is lower right corner
and don't forget to import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: Hey thanks! However I dont like using the IB, how can I do this programmatically? Do I really have to make a subclass of the UIImageView class to make it apply to all my images? Or is there another way? Thanks again :)

Comment: Btw I have heard that in objective c you can add/override methods and instance variables to and existing class without subclassing it? I want this to work for every UIIMageView I init? Is that possible?

Comment: Yeah you can override methods but not variables.. search for categories in objective c then override init method

Answer (score 0):

`UIImageView` positioning settings inherited from `UIView`. That is why you can only manipulte by `frame` and `center` properties of your `UIImageView`. But you can 'simulate' left-bottom corner positioning:

```
UIView *yourView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
int bottomLeftX, bottomLeftY;

CGRect rect = yourView.frame;
yourView.frame = CGRectMake(bottomLeftX, bottomLeftY - rect.size.height, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
```

Comment: Hmm cool thanks that works, but its a bit unpractical if I have many views to implement

Comment: Subclass `UIView` and implement `setBottomLeftCornerPostition:(CGPoint)point` method

Answer (score 0):

Answer for second question... Just import these files where you are creating uiimageview

```
@interface UIImageView (MyCategory)
- (id)init;
@end



@implementation UIImageView (MyCategory)

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1);
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

The above code may cause come problem as the init of UIImageView might be doing some other task too, so you should do like

```
@interface UIImageView (MyCategory)
- (id)initMyImageView;
@end



@implementation UIImageView (MyCategory)

- (id)initMyImageView {
    [self init];
    self.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1);
    return self;
}

@end
```

and use it like `[[UIImageView alloc] initMyImageView];`

Comment: @caswell, I know this is bad idea, as default init might be doing some other task too...but he wants to make category...so just gave him an example...let me edit it again...